# what 's the difference between application's enter point address and excuteable start address

Tags: c++, c, operating-system

Recnetly,I focus on the progress of compiling source codes.when I read book,I meet two professional words:enter point address and excuteable start address.I just know enter point address is 0x0.But I don't know the difference between them.

Comment: I think you mean "entry" point, I think the two terms are synonyms, and I think they're hardly ever 0x0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terminology is fuzzy but I think I know what you are talking about.  A language needs runtime support.  Standard for C and the C++ languages is the CRT.  The CRT needs to be initialized before the program can start running.  Opening stdout and stdin, initializing static objects, setting up signals, that sort of thing.

Two basic ways that's done, the compiler can inject a call to the initialization code in the main() entrypoint of the program.  Before the rest of the code inside main().  That's typical for simple operating systems that don't have a fancy loader.  Both the entrypoint and the executable start address are the same.  Also the reason why the language standard forbids recursing main().

Or it can be done by setting the executable start address to the runtime initialization function.  Which then in turn, after initialization, calls the program's entrypoint.  Common on fancier operating systems like Linux and Windows.

Comment: I search on the internet,the main() function is not the beginning of program,the operating system will first run a little program,then that little program will call main() function,so I think that little program maybe enter point address,main() function is excuteable start address.Can I use this way to comprehend two terms?

Comment: Sure.  Terms are fuzzy.  If the executable file format supports a start address then that's the one that points to the "little program".